# How to fix the url of a website in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a website and the url of the website is 'http://www.learningfactor.in/'. But when I am taking  the website in the browser, it is showing a 404 page error. The actual website is 'http://www.learningfactor.in/site/home'. How can I  direct to the second url from the first url. The website is coded in codeigniter. Can anyone help me out in this ?

htaccess code is shown below.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: check routes file for that.

Comment: The routes code is shown below :

Comment: $route['default_controller'] = 'home';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

Comment: you can also redirect it with controller which when asked request from first url than it redirect it to second url

Comment: can you show us your config.php file?

Comment: @Webdeveloper: where is you, home controller save

Comment: please show home controller

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that there are more elegant ways to do it, but you can just do the redirect in your **home**/default controller.

```
public function index () {
    $this->load->helper('url');
    redirect('/site/home);
}
```

In Codeigniter index method of the "default" controller is called automatically when you visit the homepage.